# A way to filter models for ModelChoiceField in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Let's say I have a ForeignKey field in my model.

```
class MyModel(StatusModel):
    site = models.ForeignKey('wagtailcore.Site', related_name='test_field', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    panels = [ FieldPanel('site') ]
```

Looks like Wagtail creates ModelForms by itself, but I need to filter models that make it to the dropdown list on my editing page.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: you can set up custom add and edit classes for ModelAdmin instances.

This is my custom add class definition:

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.views import CreateView

class GroupSiteCreateView(CreateView):
    def get_form(self, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(**kwargs)
        if form.fields.get('site'):
            sites = get_sites_for_user(self.request.user, 'add_site')
            form.fields['site'].queryset = form.fields['site'].queryset.filter(pk__in=[x.pk for x in sites])
        return form

class TableAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Table
    list_display = ('__str__', 'site')
    inspect_view_enabled = False
    create_view_class = GroupSiteCreateView
```